# svg2pdfjs: Images with external resource link are not supported

Tags: javascript, highcharts, base64, jspdf

I am trying to generate a pdf by Highcharts application. This pdf consists of both Highcharts and an image.

The below is the code for my source

https://codepen.io/WhoAmIAmWho/pen/GwXpVb

When I try to change the image for my local image (Changed the code in line 165 in JS) then it's returning me an error as

```
svg2pdfjs: Images with external resource link are not supported
```

I can download them in png format with my local image but not the pdf format.

Can any of you guide me here on how to convert the base64 to image format to embed it in the pdf.

Comment: Follow this thread: https://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=40947&p=144175#p144175